# SVG path to coincide with a segment of another path

Tags: svg

My ultimate goal is a picture of a creature with stripes, like a [tiger](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=tiger&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI4ubh2MfKAhXpvYMKHfbGBGwQ_AUIBygB&biw=1635&bih=1042), a [nautilus](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=nautilus&biw=1635&bih=1042&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHkPjz2MfKAhUBtYMKHYHGDMAQ_AUIBygB), or maybe a [monarch butterfly caterpillar](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=monarch%20caterpillar&biw=1635&bih=1042&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwio05KB2cfKAhUJt4MKHQKnAucQ_AUIBigB).

Suppose I already have a path element that describes some portion of the creature's outline, and in particular I have this segment (the red part in my first image):

```
<path d="M ... x0,y0 C x1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3 C ... " />
```

[image]

Now I want to create some new path elements to add stripes to the creature.  I need the top portions of these path to coincide with the existing outline path, or at least close enough for the human eye (the green parts in my second image, if you can make them out.)

[image]

This is a hobby project on my home computer, so as of now my development environment is Paint to sketch out preliminary models, Notepad++ to edit the SVG code, and Chrome browser to view the results.  I'm not against installing other tools if the results are worthwhile.

**What have you tried?**

Good old fashioned trial and error.  Pick some points that are probably close, write the path, save, preview.  Tweak a point or two
in the path, repeat.

**What do you think might work?**

I can imagine a wide array or potential answers, including "trial and error is the best you are going to get" up to "You should be using [[some tool I've never heard of]]."

I had wondered whether it is possible to put the outline path in a `<defs>` section and somehow use it in both the outline and the stripe.  I also suspect there is a way to input the eight x,y values of the "C" path segment and get the equation for the bezier curve.  From there, I could probably roll my own code to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a clip path.  Here's a mockup of your shape to use as our starting point.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <!-- tiger's back -->
  <path d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
  <!-- stripes -->
  <polygon points="100 0 125 200 150 0"/>
  <polygon points="175 0 200 200 225 0"/>
  <polygon points="250 0 275 200 300 0"/>
</svg>
```

To make our clipping path, we will want to start with the same path as the "tiger's back". However it needs to be a closed shape. So continue it round so that it encloses the area where the stripes will be.

Here's a snippet showing the shape of the clip path in red.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  
  <!-- tiger's back -->
  <path d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
  <!-- stripes -->
  <polygon points="100 0 125 200 150 0"/>
  <polygon points="175 0 200 200 225 0"/>
  <polygon points="250 0 275 200 300 0"/>

  <!-- clip shape -->
  <path d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50
           L 350 300 50 300 Z" fill="none" stroke="red"/>


</svg>
```

Finally, turn the path clip shape into an actual `<clipPath>` element, and use it to clip the stripes. Now the parts of the stripes that fall outside the clip path will not be drawn.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myclip">
      <path d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50
               L 350 300 50 300 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <!-- tiger's back -->
  <path d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
  <!-- stripes -->
  <g clip-path="url(#myclip)">
    <polygon points="100 0 125 200 150 0"/>
    <polygon points="175 0 200 200 225 0"/>
    <polygon points="250 0 275 200 300 0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

To define the path once and use it for both the rendered path and the clip path, do this:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  
<defs>
  <clipPath id="myclip">
    <use xlink:href="#tigerbody"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>

<!-- tiger's back -->
<path id="tigerbody" d="M 50 100 C 100 50 150 50 200 75 C 250 100 300 100 350 50
                      L 350 300 50 300 Z" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
<!-- stripes -->
<g clip-path="url(#myclip)">
  <polygon points="100 0 125 200 150 0"/>
  <polygon points="175 0 200 200 225 0"/>
  <polygon points="250 0 275 200 300 0"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that.